# Data not inserting into database to a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into a database after the user clicks on a link from file one.php. So file two.php contains the following code:

```
$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'";
$results = mysqli_query($cnx, $retrieve);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($results);
```

So the query above will get the information from the database using `$_GET[id]` as a reference. 
After this is performed, I want to insert the information retrieved in a different table using this code:

```
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$price = $row['price'];
$session = session_id();

if($count > 0) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO table2 (id, title, price, session_id)
            VALUES('$id', '$title', '$price', '$session');";
    }
```

The first query `$retrieve` is working but the second `$insert` is not. Do you have an idea why this is happening? PS: I know I will need to sanitize and use PDO and prepared statements, but I want to test this first and it's not working and I have no idea why. Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't see you executing the insert.

Comment: How will I do that? what did I miss?

Comment: similar method to your select.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing the query:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO table2 (id, title, price, session_id)
        VALUES('$id', '$title', '$price', '$session');";
}
```

it needs to use `mysqli_query()` with the db connection just as you did for the SELECT and make sure you started the session using `session_start();` seeing you're using sessions.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO table2 (id, title, price, session_id)
        VALUES('$id', '$title', '$price', '$session');";
}


$results_insert = mysqli_query($cnx, $insert);
```

basically.

Plus...

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

If that still doesn't work, then MySQL may be complaining about something, so you will need to escape your data and check for errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Sidenote:

Use `mysqli_affected_rows()` to check if the INSERT was truly successful.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I will use PDO with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of your query in PDO if you'req planning to use PDO in future.

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 (id, title, price, session_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?");
$sql->bindParam(1, $id);
$sql->bindParam(2, $title);
$sql->bindParam(3, $price);
$sql->bindParam(4, $session_id);
$sql->execute();
```

That's how we are more safe.